# Get text occurrences between newlines

Tags: java

I have this for an example

```
test¶test1¶test2¶test3
```

This should return 4

However

```
test¶test1¶test2¶
```

should return 3 because there is not text after the 3rd newline.

I can do something like

```
str.split("\n").length
```

This will only give me the amount of newlines. I'm not sure what to try to just return text between the newlines. Would regex work?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `str.split("\n").length` gives the right answer for both of your examples. Can you give an example where you want something *different* from what `str.split("\n").length` gives? That, I think, would help clarify what you want.

Comment: @ruakh I think that he need the content of lines instead of the number of lines. See my answer.

Comment: What should test¶¶test2¶ or ¶¶test2¶ return?

Comment: @beny23 test¶¶test2¶ should return 2 ¶¶test2¶ should return 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] text = str.split("\n");
for( String t : text ) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess your string by removing newlines at the beginning and end (trim) and remove duplicate newlines in the middle if needed. 
Then use your code:

```
str.split("\n").length
```

A regex doing all that would be interesting but readability would suffer.

**Edit**: The regex is easy, but you have to count the matchces:

```
    private int getMatchCount(String s){
    int count = 0;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using split from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) works for me:

```
StringUtils.split(s, "\r\n").length
```

(added the `\r` to avoid tripping over line separator issues...

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

I've used " " (whitespace) as the delimiter, you can replace \\s with \\n to get the desired result

```
public static int getNumberOfTokens(String input){
    int result = 0;
    if(!input.endsWith(" ")) input = input + " ";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(.+?)\\s+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
       ++result;
       System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively simple approach:

```
str.replaceFirst("^\n+", "").split("\n+").length
```

The `str.replaceFirst("^\n+", "")` part creates a copy of `str` with any leading newlines stripped off. The `split("\n+")` part splits the string by sequences of *one or more* newlines (so blank lines are ignored), and discards any trailing blanks.

The `"^\n+"` and `"\n+"` are simple regular expressions: `"\n+"` means "one or more consecutive newlines", and `"^\n+"` means "one or more consecutive newlines at the start of the string".

So, for example, if `str` is `"\n\nYES\nNO\n\nMAYBE\n"`, then we have:

```
 expression                                       | value
--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------
 str                                              | "\n\nYES\nNO\n\nMAYBE\n"
 str.replaceFirst("^\n+", "")                     | "YES\nNO\n\nMAYBE\n"
 str.replaceFirst("^\n+", "").split("\n+")        | {"YES", "NO", "MAYBE"}
 str.replaceFirst("^\n+", "").split("\n+").length | 3
```